# What is the best way to count and sort a string array

Tags: java, sorting, data-structures

I am trying to find if there is a good way to search (count number of occurrences) and then sort a String array in a efficient way... that is a way that will work well in embedded systems (32Mb)

Example: I have to count the number of time the character A, B, C, etc... is used save that result for posterior sorting...

I can count using a public int count(String searchDomain, char searchValue) method, but each string should have all alphabet letter for instance:

```
"This is a test string"
A:1,B:0,C:0,D:0,E:1,I:3,F:0,...
"ACAAGATGCCATTGTCCCCCGGCCTCCTGCTGCTGCTGCTCTCCGGGGCCACGGCCACCGCTGCCCTGCC"
A:7,B:0,C:22,G:18
```

My sorting method need to be able to answer to things like: Sort by number of As, Bs
sort first by As and then sort that subdomain by Bs

This is not for homework, it's for an application that needs to run on mobile phones, i need this to be efficient, my current implementation is too slow and uses too much memory.

Comment: If you are dealing with more data than you can fit into memory at once, a mergesort has good io characteristics

Comment: Can you show us your current implementation? It might be easier to optimize your current implementation than it is to start over from scratch.

Comment: I wish I code but the code is not mine to post, but it is basically a mix of dictionary with hashmap... it's runs ok, but it has a huge size that makes it unusable for mobile devices... I think perhaps it would be best to store all this in a server, still I need to be able to sort it by subdomains...

Comment: @chuck: The issue is that I can't merge the data, it has to remain available for subsequent sorting... for instance I have the top10 substrings that contain As and then I need to sort those again by number of Gs, etc... so the subdomain gets norrower and norrower until I have the final String that corresponds to the criteria.

Comment: Adam, where is all your data stored? RAM? Flash? (Can it all be loaded into main memory?) Also, what is your alphabet size? (256 characters max? Unicode? ASCII so 128 characters or less?)

Comment: Data is on RAM, My alphabet is much shorter than that, it's only 26 English letters and no numbers.

Comment: So is this data static or dynamic?

Comment: How many different sort rules does your domain have? (assuming, for example, that "Sort by number of As, Bs" is one rule).

Comment: It's very important we know more about the problem. If you can tell us the exact range of characters you can encounter, that'd help optimize. Is this an app that has something to do with dna? If that's the case, you can use a tree to store a hierarchical structure with a very small overhead. If you're only ever going to look at 4-8 characters, you can't think of your tree as a variable length tree and so your memory efficiency is a relatively small constant, even on mobile devices. Please shed more light on character ranges, etc. To optimize, we need to know more properties about the problem.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'd take advantage of Java's (very efficient) built in sorting capabilities. To start with, define a simple class to contain your string and its metadata:

```
class Item
{
    // Your string. It's public, so you can get it if you want,
    // but also final, so you can't accidentally change it.
    public final String string;

    // An array of counts, where the offset is the alphabetical position
    // of the letter it's counting. (A = 0, B = 1, C=2...)
    private final short[] instanceCounts = new short[32];

    public Item(String string)
    {
        this.string = string;
        for(char c : string.toCharArray())
        {
            // Increment the count for this character
            instanceCounts[(byte)c - 65] ++;
        }
    }

    public int getCount(char c)
    {
        return instanceCounts[(byte)c - 65];
    }
}
```

This will hold your String (for searching and display), and set up an array of shorts with the count of the matching characters. (If you're *really* low on memory and you know your strings have more than 255 of any one character, you can even change this to an array of bytes.) A short is only 16 bytes, so the array itself will only take 64 bytes all together regardless of how complex your string. If you'd rather pay the performance hit for calculating the counts every time, you can get rid of the array and replace the getCount() method, but you'll probably end up saving once-off memory by consuming frequently-garbage-collected memory, which is a big performance hit. :)

Now, define the rule you want to search on using a Comparator. For example, to sort by the number of A's in your string:

```
class CompareByNumberOfA implements Comparator<Item>
{
    public int compare(Item arg0, Item arg1) 
    {
        return arg1.getCount('A') - arg0.getCount('A');
    }
}
```

Finally, stick all of your items in an array, and use the built in (and highly memory efficient) Arrays methods to sort. For example:

```
public static void main(String args[])
{
    Item[] items = new Item[5];
    items[0]= new Item("ABC");
    items[1]= new Item("ABCAA");
    items[2]= new Item("ABCAAC");
    items[3]= new Item("ABCAAA");
    items[4]= new Item("ABBABZ");

    // THIS IS THE IMPORTANT PART!
    Arrays.sort(items, new CompareByNumberOfA());

    System.out.println(items[0].string);
    System.out.println(items[1].string);
    System.out.println(items[2].string);
    System.out.println(items[3].string);
    System.out.println(items[4].string);
}
```

You can define a whole bunch of comparators, and use them how you like.

One of the things to remember about coding with Java is not to get too clever. Compilers do a damn fine job of optimizing for their platform, as long as you take advantage of things they *can* optimize (like built-in APIs including Arrays.sort).

Often, if you try to get too clever, you'll just optimize yourself right out of an efficient solution. :)

Comment: That solution is pretty much similar to what I have at the moment, my question to you would be if there is a more compact way to store the letterIndexByteArray, that is a way to store the search results so i do not have to recalculate it, other than a lookup table I have come empty handed in this regard... with a large string domain this would require a lot of compares... what is the O(x) of Java sort?

Comment: The counting array? Do you have an upper bound on how many characters of any type there are? You can use bytes rather than shorts, and 'unsign' them by bit-masking them into integers when you're reading them. That halves the memory needed, but will break if you have a string with more than 255 of the same character. If that's still too much memory, then you need to ditch the counts table and run a single-pass searching algorithm over your strings. For that, I'd need to know more about your algorithm. (And Java sort is normally an in-situ merge sort. No extra memory required.)

Comment: @Adam Surfari Why do you need to store the full strings, which are your main memory eaters? In Erica's solution, once counted, you can store an string identifier instead of the field named `string` (shorter than the original string) so that you can retrieve the string later if you needed it.

Comment: @Adam Surfari To elaborate on this, if the app is only counting and sorting, you can have a `Problem` entity, which has a unique id and a long DNA-like string like yours. You download the object from ws, count and build your `Item` (in Item constructor you have got rid of the problem string after counting, and so it is GCable). Then when you want to use the string again, call WS with problem id and retrieve.

Comment: Right now the major drawback is that if you are instanciating 2500 strings with Item(string) they all have to be char counted, if each String contains a big amount of strings, then you have a huge startup cost, Also having static Comparators like one for A, one for B, etc... is what I was trying to avoid in the first place. Anyway, I will accept your answer since no one has proposed something better.

Comment: @AdamSurfari There may well be a more efficient solution, but I'd need to know more about your end goal. Do you actually need to do sequential sorting, or could the whole sort be done in a single pass? Do you need to store the strings, or just references? Given the information in the question, there's not much that can be done past this to optimize, but if you could provide more information we might be able to find somewhere else to save memory/time. You don't *need* to use static comparators, you could just have one that evaluates based on user input, if that's a concern.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that what you're after is a tree structure, and that in fact the question would be better rewritten talking about a tree structure to index a long continuous string rather than "count" or "sort".

I'm not sure if this is a solution or a restatement of the question.  Do you want a data-structure which is a tree, where the root has e.g. 26 sub-trees, one for strings starting with 'A', the next child for 'B', and so on;  then the 'A' child has e.g. 20 children representing "AB", "AC", "AT" etc.; and so on down to children representing e.g. "ABALXYZQ", where each child contains an integer field representing the count, i.e. the number of times that sub-string occurs?

```
class AdamTree {
    char ch;
    List<AdamTree> children;
    int count;
}
```

If this uses too much memory then you'd be looking at ways of trading off memory for CPU time, but that might be difficult to do...nothing comes to mind.

Comment: Hi Tim, no that is not what I want... I don't want to store first character or substring I want to store the number of times that char occurs for that strings and then have a subset of strings that have A>10, then I need to be able to query that subset again, for B>20, etc... until I am left with a reduced set of strings.

Comment: Okay, take 2:  You have a set of strings, and you want to answer queries on it such as:  how many (or which) strings contain more than 10 A's AND more than 13 B's AND more than 7 C's and so on?  In which case is it necessary to count the A's before the B's etc.?

Comment: @Adam Surfari: Take 3: you don't know how many A's you need, but you know that you want to take the top 100 "strings which contain many A's"?  And of that set, you want to take the top 10 "strings which contain many B's"?  And then of that set take the string which has most C's?

Comment: Hi tim, yes, that is pretty much it. I need to develop a small API and algorithms to be able to search a determined condition or set of conditions in a efficient way.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry I don't have time to write this up in a better way.  To minimize space, I would make an two m x n (dense) arrays, one byte and one short where:

- m is the number of input strings
- n is the number of characters in *each* string; this dimension varies from row to row
- the byte array contains the character
- the short array contains the count for that character

If counts are guaranteed < 256, you could just use one m x n x 2 byte array.

If the set of characters you are using is dense, i.e., the set of ALL characters used in ANY string is not much larger than the set of characters used in EACH string, you could get rid of the byte array and just use a fixed "n" (above) with a function that maps from character to index.  This is would be much faster.

This would requires 2Q traversals of this array for any query with Q clauses.  Hopefully this will be fast enough.

Answer (score 0):

I can assist with php/pseudo code and hashmaps or associative arrays.

```
$hash="";

$string = "ACAAGATGCCATTGTCCCCCGGCCTCCTGCTGCTGCTGCTCTCCGGGGCCACGGCCACCGCTGCCCTGCC"
while ( read each $char from $string ) {

  if ( isset($hash[$char]) ) { 
      $hash[$char] = $hash[$char]+1 
  } else {
      $hash[$char]=1
  }
}
```

at the end you'll have an associative array with 1 key / char found
and in the hash value you'll have the count of the occurences

It's not PHP (or any other language for that matter) but the principle should help.

Comment: My problem is not counting the chars, it more about creating an efficient datastructure that is able to store the count data and is sortable by subdomains or subsets... perhaps i need to make my question clearer?

Answer (score 0):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm
Have a look at the KMP algorithm. This is a rather common programming problem. Above you will find one of the fastest solutions possible. Easy to understand and implement.

Count the occurences with KMP then either go with a merge sort after insertion, or if you know that the array/etc is sorted, go with binary search/direction insertion.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use a kind of tree structure, where the depth corresponds to a given letter. Each node in the tree thus corresponds to a letter + a count of occurrences of that letter. If only one string matches this node (and its parent nodes), then it is stored in the node. Otherwise, the node has child nodes for the next letters and the letter count.

This would thus give something like this:

```
A:     0                  1                   3           ...
       |               /     \              /    \
B:     0             0        1           1        3
      / \          heaven   /   \     barracuda    ababab
C:   0   1                 0     1
   foo   cow             bar     bac
```

Not sure this would cost less than the array count solution but at least you wouldn't have to store the count for all letters for all strings (the tree stops when the letter count uniquely identifies a string)

You could probably optimize it by cutting long branches without siblings

Answer (score 0):

You could try the code in Java below

```
int[] data = new int[254];//we have 254 different characters 
void processData(String mString){

    for (int i=0 ; i< mString.length;i++){
       char c = mString.charAt(i); 
        data[c]++;
    }
}
int getCountOfChar(char c){
     return data[c];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems there's some confusion on what your requirements and goals are.

If your search results take up too much space, why not "lossily compress" (like music compression) the results? Kind of like a hash function.  Then, when you need to retrieve results, your hash indicates a much smaller subset of strings that needed to be searched properly with a more lengthy searching algorithm.

If you actually store the `String` objects, and your strings are actually human readable text, you could try deflating them with `java.util.zip` after you're done searching and index and all that.  If you *really* want to keep them tiny and you don't receive actual `String` objects, and you said you only have 26 different letters, you can compress them into groups of 5 bits and store them like that.  Use the `CharSequence` interface for this.